# Регулярные выражения в форме регистрации

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как учесть только латиницу или кирилицу?

Есть форма регистрации, мне нужно учесть только русские или латинские буквы, но смешивать их нельзя. Пример: "Lexans" и "Алексей" - разрешено, а "Lexaнс" - нет!

Вот как такое учесть?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/^([A-Za-z]+|[А-Яа-я]+)$/u`
Вот такая регулярка

Comment: Отдельно ё нужно в русские буквы добавить, она не входит в а-я.

Comment: Вот такая вот неправильная "регулярка". На 5+ :)

Comment: Кругом одни неучи ;)

Comment: Может умники выше ответят в чем неправильность регулярки, кроме того что нет ё?